# Entity framework with Firebird throws dynamic SQL error

Tags: entity-framework-6, firebird2.1

I've got stuck with FbException

> SQL error code = -104
>
> Token unknown - line 2, column 4
>
> .

when trying to run this code

```
var result = from x in _context.Bunts
                         select x;
```

I've checked the query which was produced by EF

```
SELECT 
"A"."BUNTCODE" AS "BUNTCODE", 
"A"."BUNTNAME" AS "BUNTNAME", 
"A"."BUNTDIAM" AS "BUNTDIAM"
FROM "BUNTS" AS "A"
```

So server thinks that something is wrong with dot after "A" statement. But this query runs just fine in IBExpert on the same machine. How to fix this problem?

I'm using:

> Firebird server v2.1.6.18547
>
> EntityFramework v6.0.0.0
>
> EntityFramework.Firebird v4.5.2.0
>
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 4.5.2.0

Comment: What is the dialect of your database? And what is your connection dialect? The error seems to suggest you are connecting using dialect 1 (where you can't quote object names, and things in double quotes are strings).

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark! Switching to dialect 3 solved my problem!

Comment: I wish that the Firebird core developers would finally kill dialect 1 (and 2); dialect 3 was introduced 15 years ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests you are connecting using dialect 1. Dialect 1 is the old dialect of Interbase 5 and earlier and should be considered deprecated (although unfortunately 15 years on it is still supported by Firebird...).

In dialect 1 it is not possible to quote object names, and double quotes are used for strings (instead of single quotes in dialect 3 and the SQL standard). When your query is parsed in dialect 1, Firebird sees `"A"` as a string constant, and the following dot (`.`) is not expected by the parser.

Switching to dialect 3 should fix this, however if you do that, make sure that your database itself is also dialect 3, otherwise you might get other unexpected behavior like certain datatypes not working, or errors, etc.

Comment: Holy cow! You are a life saver!! I changed it in a connection string and it works like a charm :D

Comment: @Voyak Unless your connection string incorrectly specified dialect 1, just changing the connection dialect is not really the correct solution if your database is actually still dialect 1. Rebuilding the database as a dialect 3 database, and pumping the data over should be preferred.

Comment: Changing the database is not an option im my case unfortunately. But I will keep that in mind :)